# SQL server database start/stop issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise for development. I find from SQL Server logs, there are items like,

```
2009-09-20 19:54:33.55 spid53      Starting up database 'DummyOrderDB'.
```

My confusion is, I think we could only start/stop database server instance (the contained database will be started/stopped when the containing database server instance start/stop), can we just start/stop a database without touch database server instance? I did not find such menu from SSMS.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an `auto close` database. Auto-close databases are 'closed' when not in use and each time an user uses one, they run a short recovery and the text above is displayed. SQL Express creates databases as auto close `ON` by default. To turn off the auto-close behavior, run:

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SEt AUTO_CLOSE OFF;
```

Comment: What do you mean "each time an user uses one"? Can you speak in some other words please?

Comment: Each time the user issues `USE <dnbname>;` or opens a session with `Initial Catalog=<dbname>`.

Comment: Or runs a query that references the database
eg 
SELECT * FROM <dbname>.dbo.SomeTable

Comment: Thanks! If I am using SQL Server connection pool at ADO.Net client side, and I am wondering any impact to my clide code using ADO.Net? Suppose for a period of time, I do not connect DB using connection pool connection, then after some time, when I re-connect, will connection fail because of auto-closed? Or connection pool will handle reconnect issue?

Comment: I read the following statements from MSDN but confused -- "The database automatically reopens when a user tries to use the database again. For example, by issuing a USE database_name statement. If the database is shut down cleanly while AUTO_CLOSE is set to ON, the database is not reopened until a user tries to use the database the next time the Database Engine is restarted." from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx, does it mean if we set autoclose on, and after db closed, when a client reconnects, db will automatically reconnect? No impact to client (like ADO.Net code)?

Comment: Right, the database re-opens automatically. This is completely transparent for the client.

Comment: 1. I think if I set autoclose will degrade performance of connection pool at client side (using ADO.Net connection pool), is that true? 2. Are there any comment (e.g. I can try from dbcc) to stop database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can.  Of course Starting and Stopping databases only make sense when the server itself is started  (that helps ;-) ),  but each individual database has to be, say, *initialized* before it can be used in earnest.  Also when you detach a database, it first shuts down. (which ensures data integrity and other clean-up are taken care of etc.)

Comment: Thanks, can we use command to explicitly control databse level start/stop?

Comment: Yes.
If you don't want it happening automatically, switch auto_close off. It's not a good setting on a busy production database anyway.

You can close a database by taking it offline - Alter Database <dbname> Set offline

Comment: Taking offline means the same thing as stop database? Do you have any docunments to prove? :-)

Comment: I read the following statements from MSDN but confused -- "The database automatically reopens when a user tries to use the database again. For example, by issuing a USE database_name statement. If the database is shut down cleanly while AUTO_CLOSE is set to ON, the database is not reopened until a user tries to use the database the next time the Database Engine is restarted." from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx, does it mean if we set autoclose on, and after db closed, when a client reconnects, db will automatically reconnect? No impact to client (like ADO.Net code)?